# Shutdown goes to uninterruptible sleep after sending wall message

Tags: linux, debian, process, debian-squeeze

I have a server which I'm administrating remotely over SSH, for various reasons, it needs to be restarted. However, when I try to do so, `shutdown` goes to uninterruptible sleep almost immediately after sending the wall message.

```
$ ps aux | grep 'shutdown'
root      4754  0.0  0.1   1888   720 ?        D    07:26   0:00 shutdown -r 0 w
```

I have no physical access to the machine at the current time. What should I do? The server is still responding, and I can still log in.

Comment: Does the server have NFS mounts? Is it connected to SAN via Fibre Channel? Is there some kind of heartbeat system such as Heartbeat v2 installed?

Comment: True, it's probably worth giving background: this server is one of the backend servers for a large LAN event I am administrating. It mostly handles the bots for our our internal IRC network, and we also use it for anything large we need to store on a whim (8TB storage). It is also running `rtorrent`.

Comment: Large LAN event? [Assembly](http://www.assembly.org/)? :D Ok, now that I got that said ... what does `lsof -n -p 4754` tell you?

Comment: I found this question trying to figure out what happened when you have an uninterruptible-sleep process and try to shut down. I expect now I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

State D is not "dead", it's blocked waiting on disk IO.

Something like "reboot -n -f" is more forceful and may work. Are you having filesystem trouble? The shutdown command writes a wtmp entry before telling init to shut down.

Comment: I'm not having filesystem trouble as far as I am aware, but it's starting to sound more and more like it...

Comment: "reboot -n -f" should avoid the disk IO that shutdown is doing, and it should cause the kernel to reboot. Or crash. I suspect at least something will happen. :)

Comment: Here goes nothing!

Comment: That did it, thanks. Did seem to wreck the journal on `/dev/sdb1`, but all is well now. http://sprunge.us/ZGAS

Comment: @neurolysis: A brave, brave man you are. :-) I have also used `reboot -nf` sometimes but then I've made sure I have physical access to server ... but perhaps you had someone available for that.

Comment: Brave and/or stupid :p Yeah, I had omeone on the phone whilst it rebooted, but I don't think he would have known what to do if it went wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Enable the Magic SysRq key with:

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
```

and do the clean reboot with following steps:

1. Alt + SysRq + e
2. Alt + SysRq + u
3. Alt + SysRq + i
4. Alt + SysRq + b

Comment: Computer is now rebooted w/ `reboot -n -f`, but thanks. What caused it, however, eludes me.

Comment: He only had access to the server via ssh, SysRq won't work.

Comment: You can send the command key to sysrq-trigger: `echo "key" > /proc/sysrq-trigger`.

Answer (score 1):

`shutdown` is probably waiting to write to something like `/dev/initctl` -- use `strace -p 4754` to see where it's hanging, then fix whatever is broken.

Comment: There is absolutely no output from `strace`. It states `Process 4754 attached - interrupt to quit`, but then there is nothing.

Comment: Then you've got bigger problems than a machine that won't shut down.  D state is only for processes that are waiting for an I/O related syscall to complete.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen shutdown hanging if there are (stale) NFS mounts or server is connected to SAN. Here's a checklist for you:

- Can you still see all the disk mounts with `df -h` (or otherwise access the mounts)?
- Are there other processes than `shutdown` in `D` state?
- Does `dmesg` return you something about I/O or is there even a nice little kernel panic waiting for you?
- If there are processes using some SAN/NFS mount, can you stop those processes manually, verify with `lsof` that no files are open on that mount, and then `umount` that mount?
- If `btrace` is installed, does `btrace /your/disk` return something?

Should everything else fail, the SysRq stanza provided by @quanta should work, BUT first make sure there's someone who can physically babysit the server if it for some reason does not boot cleanly.

Comment: Already rebooted now, but thanks. Don't think there was anything else in D state. Will see if there is anything interesting in the post-reboot `dmesg` now. I don't have any SAN/NFS mounts on the machine.

Comment: Are disk quotas in use? I've seen them causing hangs with ext3 filesystem, though that was like seven years ago and with a server with tens of thousands of users ...

Comment: Nope. Only interesting stuff I see is here: http://sprunge.us/YXCf

Comment: This drives me nuts. :-) Since you have 8 TB of data, is LVM in use? Perhaps you have LVM snapshots and those caused some kind of hickup during shutdown. Oh well, better stop guessing.

Comment: No LVM. This is troubling. Oh well! I guess I've just got to wait for the next exciting phone call I get to tell me the server room is on fire. :-)